# How soon can I release a watchOS app?

Tags: swift

Since WWDC 2015, there's a lot improvements for for Apple Watch with it's new watchOS - we have finally access to Digital Crown, Taptic Engine and so on. That being said, how soon can I release watchOS app, which is using those new APIs? Is it when watchOS will be officially released, or when public beta will be out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple will probably not begin to accept apps created for watchOS 2 before we get closer to the actual release of the operative system.

As a reference, Apple started to ask developers to submit their apps targeted Apple Watch (the first version of the OS) on march 31, only about 25 days before the release of the Apple Watch.
Also as a reference to WWDC14 apple asked developers to start submitting their apps for iOS 8 in mid september.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait until the release version is out - which means when Xcode 7 is out of beta (and that should include all of swift 2.0, iOS9 and watchOS 2)